# How to modify consumer, so it can handle similar objects?

Tags: java

Let me explain my behaviour with the following example:

I've got two similar Address Classes, with three similar informations, but different method names.

**Address**
 - *setNr, setCode, setStreetname,* setHabitants

**OtherAddress**
 - *setNumber, setPostalcode, setStreet,* setSize

I'm using an Address-Typed Consumer, that manipulates data of "Address" element.

Now I want to use the same Consumer with "OtherAddress", because same manipulation shall be done, on the similar methods.

```
public class AddressManipulateConsumer implements Consumer<Address> {

        @Override
        public void accept(Address address) {

        address.setNr("22");
        address.setCode("12345");
        address.setStreetname("examplestr.");
        }
 }
```

my aim is to avoid duplicate the class:

```
public class AddressManipulateConsumer implements Consumer<OtherAddress> {

        @Override
        public void accept(OtherAddress address) {

        address.setNumber("22");
        address.setPostalcode("12345");
        address.setStreet("examplestr.");
        }

 }
```

What are the stepts or ways for solving it?

Comment: Can you use the same method names in both?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking for, maybe the visitor pattern?

Comment: no, they are different classes, but I want to manipulate same sort of data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following the below steps:

1) Create an adapter of `OtherAddresses` ("`OtherAddressAdapter`") with function names similar as Address

2) Create a parent Interface `AddressWrapper` having these 4 functions and make `OtherAddressAdapter` and `Address` implement this interface

3) Create consumer like below:

```
public class AddressManipulateConsumer implements Consumer<AddressWrapper> {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use an *adaptor* for `OtherAddress`

```
 class OtherAddressAdaptor extends Address {
     OtherAddress hiddenObject;

     OtherAddressAdaptor(OtherAddress hiddenObject) {...}

     @Override
     void setNr(String number) {
         this.hiddenObject.setNumber(number);
     }

     // do the same thing for other methods
}
```

Now, instead of using an `OtherAddress` object, create an `OtherAddressAdaptor` from it, and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface for the 3 common methods:

```
interface BasicAddress {
    void setNumber(String number);
    void setPostalcode(Stting code);
    void setStreet(String street);
    // getters too
}
```

Make `Address` and `OtherAddress` implement `BasicAddress` and rename the current methods to be aligned. They *should* use the same names anyway because they’re dealing with the same concepts.

Have the consumer accept `BasicAddress`:

```
public class AddressManipulateConsumer implements Consumer<BasicAddress> {
    @Override
    public void accept(BasicAddress address) {
        address.setNumber("22");
        address.setPostalcode("12345");
        address.setStreet("examplestr.");
    }
 }
```